# matrix generator - segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, matrix, segmentation-fault

I have the following function for generating a symmetric matrix:

```
void genMatrix(int n, double A[n][n])
 {

int i,j;
int count=0;
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
for (j=i+1; j<n; j++)
    {
    count++;
    A[i][j]=count;
    A[j][i]=count;
    }

 }
```

When i call the function with these parameters:

```
int n = 10000;
double A[n][n];
genMatrix(n,A);
```

it gives me a segmentation fault, and i don't understand why. I also tried filling the matrix only with 1 values but it doesn't change anything.
What could be the problem? With smaller n values like 1000 it works fine.

Comment: This uses VLA, variable length arrays, that don't exist in C++. So I took out the C++ tag.

Comment: Please tell us: 1) the system you are using, 2), the language you are using 3) the compiler you are using. I don't see anything wrong apart that I cannot compile because on following line my Microsoft compiler extects a constant expression for n in A[n][n]n: "void genMatrix(int n, double A[n].[n])". Looks somethign else than C.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, this is C with VLA, so at least C99. Microsoft compilers never made it to that.

Comment: @Jens Gusted: thanks for the information. I never made it to that either :-)

Comment: gcc compiler, ubuntu system

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably just getting a stack overflow here. The array is too big to fit in your program's stack address space.

If you allocate the array on the heap you should be fine, assuming your machine has enough memory.

Comment: what do you mean by allocate the array on the heap?

Comment: @biggdman, please read about dynamic allocation in C, `malloc` and `free` are the functions that you are looking for

Comment: @biggdman [use dynamic allocation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709099/should-i-make-stack-segment-large-or-heap-segment-large?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: @biggdman, your questions show that you need to read on, first. SO is not a site for discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You try to create a 400 megabytes array on the stack? That will hardly work. Most modern operating systems have stacks in the range of one to four megabytes.

Answer (score 0):

This allocates a very large matrix on the "stack" of your function. This is not a good idea, you have a "stackoverflow".

Comment: if i would replicate the code of the function in main, would that make it alright?

Answer (score 0):

well, it seems like your array is too big to fit in your program's stack address space. since it's size is of

> 381.47 MB

it is just too big, windows for example gives you only

> 1MB

stack by default

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create an automatic variable with a size of 800MB (assuming that `double` is 64 bits). On most platforms, automatic variables are created on a stack, and the total size of that stack is typically only a few megabytes. Allocating anything too big will cause a stack overflow and (if you're lucky) a segmentation fault. It's best to allocate huge objects dynamically.

Comment: @biggdman: In C, use `malloc`. The question was originally tagged C++ too (although the code isn't valid C++); in that language, prefer containers like `std::vector`.

Comment: @cf16: The SI unit "mega", represented by "M", means 10^6, and that's what I mean here. Some people may abuse it to mean 2^20 (or even 10^3 * 2^10), but that's not what I mean here.